# KnockoutJS: how do observables track UI changes?

Tags: knockout.js

If I have multiple `<ul>`'s each with its own draggable child `<li>`'s, and I drag-n-drop the items between the lists (aka a connected list), how does KO keep track of these changes? Evidently the ViewModel doesn't keep track of the changes, so I guess the question is how can they be tracked?

HTML:

```
<section>
    <ul class="connected" data-bind="foreach: fieldsCol1" id="list1">
        <li data-bind="attr: {id: id}">New Field</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="connected" data-bind="foreach: fieldsCol2" id="list2">
        <li data-bind="attr: {id: id}">New Field</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

View Model:

```
function VM() {
    this.fieldsCol1 = ko.observableArray([some array]);
    this.fieldsCol2 = ko.observableArray([some array]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

In above example moving items between `list1` and `list2` doesn't reflect on `fieldsCol1` or `fieldsCol2`.

Btw I am using a jQuery library that allows above DND behaviour.

Comment: @Hans, you should turn that into an answer. Vanilla KO has no features for drag/drop, it will just order elements they way they're ordered in the VM. You shouldn't change that order in the DOM yourself, but use a plugin instead. Mentioned knockout-sortable works like a charm for us, handling exactly this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an easy problem to solve: These sorts of libraries usually involve detaching elements from the DOM, and inserting them somewhere else. Possibly they clone elements in the process. These sort of libraries aren't aware of the bindings Knockout creates, and tend to mess them up. To patch this isn't an easy task. For inspiration, take a look at the Knockout sortable plugin: http://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: I once wrote my own drag and drop ko binding. It worked *almost* all  the time. I was so happy when I discovered Ryan's implementation! Not only does it work well, it provides a great reference for writing similar bindings.

Comment: This is really exciting. But there's an "ouch" for me; I am not using jQuery UI (and I don't have any uses for it). I was even going to find an alternative jQuery-less solution to my current sortable functionality.